# .htaccess file is throwing a 500 error after trying to clean up url

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, url, http-status-code-500

I am trying to clean up my urls with an .htaccess file but whenever I put in the last rule, it gives me a 500 error. What I am trying to do is whenever the use goes to website.com/team/create it is actually calling a file named /team/createteam.php. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Previous to this I did the exact same thing but with my news route and it works. Any help would be greatly appreaciated. Here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# Remove Extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# News
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/create /news/createnews.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/show/([0-9]+) /news/shownews.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/edit/([0-9]+) /news/editnews.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

# Team 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^team/create /team/createteam.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the .htaccess throwing the error and not the /team/createteam.php script?

Comment: im pretty sure it's not the script. I can access the page when i type in the actual file in the url

Comment: Go check what the server error log has to say. That is _always_ the first thing to do, when you get a 500, and it is not immediately obvious why.